# How to stop the video in viewpager in android

Tags: android

In my viewpager i have several page like html,gif and videos but my video not stoping after move to next screen.i want to play video file when viewpager show videoview.
how is it possible any one please answer me.

Comment: Use viewpage listener to find the page and stop the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MyPagerAdapter pageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    }

    private OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

        int currentPosition = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {

            FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide = (FragmentLifecycle)pageAdapter.getItem(currentPosition);
            fragmentToHide.onPauseFragment();

            FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle)pageAdapter.getItem(newPosition);
            fragmentToShow.onResumeFragment();

            currentPosition = newPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
    };

}
```

adaptar

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new FragmentBlue());
        fragments.add(new FragmentGreen());
        fragments.add(new FragmentPink());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

interface

```
public interface FragmentLifecycle {

    public void onPauseFragment();
    public void onResumeFragment();

}
```

fragment 1

```
public class FragmentBlue extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle {

    private static final String TAG = FragmentBlue.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseFragment() {
         //pause your video player
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragment() {

    }
}
```

fragment 2

```
public class FragmentGreen extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle{

    private static final String TAG = FragmentGreen.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_green, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseFragment() {
        //pause your video player
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.e(TAG, " onDestroyView()");
    }
}
```

Comment: this override method not working, am getting not suitable method found to override error